# How to create a list that looks like a chart legend?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, charts, microsoft-word-2016

I'm trying to describe the different parts of an image (here, the Sublime Text interface)
I've highlighted multiple zones of it with colored rectangles

I'm now trying to define what's in each of these rectangles, for that, I want to to some king of buletted list were the bullets would be little colored squares(according to each rectangle) at the begining of each line, much like a chart legend... but without the chart

Here's the image :

[image: Described image]

Is there any clean way to do that without having to insert square shapes next to my text ?

EDIT :
After applying the accepted answer :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way for that.

1. You can define your own list style:

   - go to home - paragraph - open drop down next to bullets and select "define new bullet"
   - click to symbol to select the character you want
   - click on font and set the color of the bullet in "font color"
   - define all the colors you'll use
2. set the list

   - select your whole list and apply first bullet style on it
   - select second line and remove bullet from it
   - apply your preferred style on the second line
   - do it for all items

[image]